# How do I model a padded surface?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model a padded room like this one: [image]

or like this one:[image]

How is this achievable? I am also going to use a subdivision surface modifier in the end.

Comment: Here's a tutorial on a similar patter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TazuIOUgrEI

Comment: The final purpose would make a difference to some of the method:  Hi / Lo poly? Game? Close-up?

Comment: @RobinBetts thank you for responding, it needs to be high poly.